# NetworkX: Path between edges

Tags: python, arrays, path, networkx

I have an array that looks like this (the array was created by converting a TIF slope raster)

```
[[ 15.26072407  16.01073837  27.81685448  24.49266815  32.94010162]
 [ 26.0834446   21.01086426  30.02531815  25.44641304  19.48436928]
 [ 21.98579979  19.06574059  24.44838905  26.67520905  26.61030769]
 [ 20.42549133  28.58900261  17.00629425  31.25236893  32.34066772]
 [  8.33120537  24.303339     7.85025167  35.50911713  29.56856346]]
```

I converted this array into a graph. The first node in the array looks like this:

```
>>> G[1]
{0: {'weight': 26.083444595336914}, 1: {'weight': 21.0108642578125}, 2: {'weight': 19.06574058532715}, 3: {'weight': 28.58900260925293}, 4: {'weight': 24.3033390045166}}
```

Now I like to find the shortest path between Node 1, Edge 3 and Node 4, Edge 1.
Is that possible or do I have to set up my graph in a different way?
I it is possible, how would I do it. I was only able to find the paths between nodes (e.g. `nx.shortest_path(G,source=0,target=4)` not between edges.

---

The TIF is first convert to an array with GDAL:

```
import gdal, numpy
import networkx as nx

# Open data
input_raster = "slope5.tif"
raster = gdal.Open(input_raster)

# read raster as arrays
bandraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = bandraster.ReadAsArray()

G = nx.DiGraph(arr)
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'node 1, edge 3'? nodes are 'things that can be connected', and edges are connections between them - do you really mean 'the edge between node 1 and node 3', or something else? in your case, the obvious shortest path (though edge->edge doesn't really make sense) would be to go through node 1.

Comment: I guess then my graph is wrong. In the array are 25 entries. So I should also have 25 nodes. But I only have five. For each node I have then five edges. But these edges should be nodes. So I have to find a better way converting the array to a graph (or the TIF to a graph).

Comment: Can you show us how you converted the array to a graph?

Comment: @tcaswell I added it to the question

Comment: First, `G[1]` is the second node because python starts counting at 0 ;).  How do you want to interpret 25 values as connecting 25 nodes with weight?  5 nodes fully connected (`arr[i, j]` -> weight from node i to node j) including self loops is how networkx is interpreting the input.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that python starts counting at 0. I am not quite understand what you mean/ask. Basically I have 25 nodes (each node has one weight). Each node connects to eight other nodes (besides it is at the border). My question is how to get that information from the tiff (or array) to the graph. Could you please explain further what you mean.